# Yii preg match Not allowed Numbers only

Tags: php

How to avoid numbers only in Name Validation in php? I want to do Name Allowed space,dot,special character,string but not allowed Numbers only How?

Am using below code,

```
array('first_name,last_name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/u', 'message' => '{attribute} contain Alphabets only',),
```

It not allowed Special character too?

Comment: try this $words = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $words );

Comment: If u r using `preg_match` u can use it like this `!preg_match('/^([^0-9]*)$/')`, it won't match numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string='a123';
if(preg_match('/[0-9]/',$string)){
    echo 'you are not allowed to use numbers';
}else{
    //proceed
}

?>
```

Comment: Php it's working Suppose Yii framework means how to validate array('first_name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z .\-]+$/i', 'message' => '{attribute} contain Alphabets only'), How to write pattern in this?

Comment: Huh, that's what he actually wanted :) Then that's a poor solution in terms of a name validation. He passes everything except numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will allowed space, dot, special character, string but not allowed Numbers only. that you want.

```
<?php
$words = 'string@1323_';
$words = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $words );
echo $words;
?>
```

Comment: The question is about validation, but not replacement.

Comment: According to user question "Am using below code,

/^[a-zA-Z .\-]+$/i
It not allowed Special character too?"

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to *validate* a name where the only allowed characters are letters, space, dot and `-`, then I'd use the following:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\p{L} \.\-]+$/u', $name)) {
  // $name is valid
}
```

I've used [Unicode character property](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) `\p{L}` which stands for a Unicode letter.

Numbers are not allowed simply because they are not listed in the set of allowed characters.